# how to create texture for modelmesh?

Tags: xna, c#, textures, hlsl

Is there a possibiltiy to create a texture from a meshpart in xna. By getting a flat version of the mesh. So I can create a texture for it and edit that texture(via rendertarget)? I need to get the texture(wich is not yet a texture) so I can put another texture on it.

I can create a texture and put it on a certain mesh. But I just cant figure out how I can create a texture with the right size.

I also already found out i can use text2dproj in hlsl. But when i do this i get a gray stripe in the look.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. Do you have a model where there are UV-coordinates assigned? Or have you generated a model and wonder how to get UV-coordinates?

Comment: I'm also confused. Are you trying to apply a texture, or extract one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to put an image over my model. I have finally done this with text2dproj. I was going wrong with the matrixes :$ But i finaly made it right.